# From where does the ldd command retrieve dependency information?

Tags: c, linux

Kindly bare if the question is very basic. ldd command displays the dependent libraries over the executable file is what i know. In executable file, where these information is kept?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is stored in the `.dynamic` section of the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable. See [ELF-64 Object File Format](http://downloads.openwatcom.org/ftp/devel/docs/elf-64-gen.pdf), starting on page 14 (Dynamic Tables):

> Dynamically-bound object ﬁles will have a `PT_DYNAMIC` program header entry. 
>   This program header entry refers to a segment containing the `.dynamic` section, 
>   whose contents are an array of `Elf64_Dyn` structures.

Comment: aix, thanks for the reply. :). does it differ from .plt table ? As for as i understand, .plt contains the unresolved symbols right ?

Comment: But you also need to refer to shared object dynamic libraries (e.g. `libc.so`) not only symbols (e.g. `malloc`)